# How to change schema dynamically?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe schema is as below:

```
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- n number of fields
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- ts_ms: long (nullable = true)
```

the below and after have same set of fields with same name and they are dynamic. 
I want the schema to be as below:

```
root
 |    |-- after_id: long (nullable = false)  
 |    |-- after_name: string (nullable = false) 
 |    |-- before_id: long (nullable = false)  
 |    |-- before_name: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = false)
```

I'm looking for a way to flatten the nested structure and a way to avoid duplication of field names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is more about developing an algorithm to deal with a recursive data structures than Spark per se. I've got no ready-to-use solution, but I'll give you some tools that might help you out a bit.

---

A schema is `StructType` that can have zero, one or more fields with `StructTypes` among them.

All the possible types are in [org.apache.spark.sql.types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package) package.

Let's (re)create the schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = new StructType().add(
  StructField("value", new StructType().add(
    StructField("before", new StructType().add(
      StructField("id", LongType))))))
scala> println(schema.treeString)
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

You should easily create more sophisticated ones.

`schema.fields` gives you access to the `StructFields` at the current level. Simply copy and paste them until you find another `StructType` that you'd recursively process. And so on. You know the drill.

---

Something I found out just today that may be of some help is a typed `select` that can do the flattening out of the box. That requires case classes for every "level" which may not be very helpful with this "dynamic" requirement, but worth to consider.

Let's (re)create the schema using case classes.

```
case class Before(id: Long)
case class After(id: Long)
case class Value(before: Before, after: After)
case class Data(value: Value)
```

With these case classes, you could simply do the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val schema = Encoders.product[Data].schema
scala> println(schema.treeString)
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

That's the schema above.

With that, you can flatten for free:

```
val vs = Seq(Data((Value(Before(0), After(1))))).toDF
scala> vs.select($"value".as[Value]).printSchema
root
 |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

Enough `select`s and you should be fine.